# Dynamically loop through htmlwidgets and add knitr formatting for RMarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, htmlwidgets

I am trying to dynamically create and loop through `htmlwidgets` such as `DT`, `plotly`, or `rbokeh` to generate an automated knitr report. Is there a way to add `knitr` formatting, such as the `tabset`, into the `tagList` approach outlined in this github question https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/pull/110? I have also posted this question there.

Below is some example code of what I am thinking, but it does not quite work. What I am trying to do is create 10 tabs, each with a copy of the plot generated from `plot_list`. What happens right now is all of the plots go into the last tab. In practice, `plot_list` would have different plots/tables.

```
#' ---
#' title: htmltools::tagList test
#' output:
#'    html_document
#' ---

#' # {.tabset}
#+ results='asis', echo=FALSE
library(plotly)
library(printr)

plot_list = lapply(1:10, 
                   function(i){ 
                     as.widget(plot_ly(iris, 
                                       x = iris[["Sepal.Length"]],
                                       y = iris[["Sepal.Width"]], 
                                       mode = "markers")) 
                    } 
                  )

htmltools::tagList( lapply(1:10, 
                            function(i) {
                              pandoc.header(paste0("Tab",i,' {.tabset}'), 2)
                              plot_list[[i]]
                            } 
                          )
                   )

# rmarkdown::render("your_path/htmltoolsTagList_test.r")
```

Before, I was successfully doing something like this with nested for-loops, but once I tried using figures with HTML dependencies, the figures of course do not render as they are no longer top level expressions. Is it possible in `knitr` to loop like this?

A follow up question I have is: suppose I wanted to nest these tabs into another set of tabs created the same way, is that possible? What I mean to ask is, can I nest tabs dynamically using a method like this, analogous to a nested for-loop?

I am still learning how to use `knitr`, and would appreciate any help!
Thank you!

Comment: I just demonstrated a little over on the Github issue.  Let me know if it helps.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll copy my response to the Github issue below.

Good question, and I think others will be helped by this discussion.  It might be easiest to start by building something like what you propose from scratch without the aid of `rmarkdown`.

#### manually build

```
# https://github.com/ramnathv/htmlwidgets/pull/110#issuecomment-216562703

library(plotly)
library(htmltools)
library(markdown)
library(shiny)

browsable(
  attachDependencies(
    tagList(
      tags$div(
        class="tabs",
        tags$ul(
          class="nav nav-tabs",
          role="tablist",
          tags$li(
            tags$a(
              "data-toggle"="tab",
              href="#tab-1",
              "Iris"
            )
          ),
          tags$li(
            tags$a(
              "data-toggle"="tab",
              href="#tab-2",
              "Cars"
            )
          )
        ),
        tags$div(
          class="tab-content",
          tags$div(
            class="tab-pane active",
            id="tab-1",
            as.widget(
              plot_ly(
                iris,
                x = iris[["Sepal.Length"]],
                y = iris[["Sepal.Width"]], 
                mode = "markers"
              )
            )
          ),
          tags$div(
            class="tab-pane",
            id="tab-2",
            as.widget(
              plot_ly(
                cars,
                x = speed,
                y = dist, 
                mode = "markers"
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    # attach dependencies
    #  see https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/R/html_document.R#L235
    list(
      rmarkdown::html_dependency_jquery(),
      shiny::bootstrapLib()
    )
  )
)
```

#### in rmarkdown

There is probably a better way to make this work, but until someone sets me straight, we can take the approach from above and use it in `rmarkdown`.  Unfortunately, this is still very manual.  For more reference, here is the [code](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/a40b2f57e7b461297603ee72453028b5ba4a02fc/inst/rmd/h/navigation-1.0/tabsets.js) that RStudio uses to build `tabsets`.

````
---
title: "tabs and htmlwidgets"
author: "Kent Russell"
date: "May 3, 2016"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)
library(magrittr)

# make a named list of plots for demonstration
#  the names will be the titles for the tabs
plots <- list(
  "iris" = plot_ly(
    iris,
    x = iris[["Sepal.Length"]],
    y = iris[["Sepal.Width"]], 
    mode = "markers"
  ),
  "cars" = plot_ly(
    cars,
    x = speed,
    y = dist, 
    mode = "markers"
  )
)

# create our top-level div for our tabs
tags$div(
  # create the tabs with titles as a ul with li/a
  tags$ul(
    class="nav nav-tabs",
    role="tablist",
    lapply(
      names(plots),
      function(p){
        tags$li(
          tags$a(
            "data-toggle"="tab",
            href=paste0("#tab-",p),
            p
          )
        )
      }
    )
  ),
  # fill the tabs with our plotly plots
  tags$div(
    class="tab-content",
    lapply(
      names(plots),
      function(p){
         tags$div(
          #  make the first tabpane active
          class=ifelse(p==names(plots)[1],"tab-pane active","tab-pane"),
          #  id will need to match the id provided to the a href above
          id=paste0("tab-",p),
          as.widget(plots[[p]])
        )
      }
    )
  )
) %>%
  # attach the necessary dependencies
  #  since we are manually doing what rmarkdown magically does for us
  attachDependencies(
    list(
      rmarkdown::html_dependency_jquery(),
      shiny::bootstrapLib()
    )
  )
```
````

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Kent! I really appreciate it. I am still digesting it, and am still working to see if I can nest `tabsets` in this fashion. I had a question, however. To compile this code, I had to remove the line `shiny::bootstrapLib()`, so I was wondering what that line of code does? I made sure to update my packages - perhaps you could share your `sessionInfo()`? Again, thank you so much!

Comment: `shiny::bootstrapLib()` is a helper function in lines https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/R/bootstrap.R#L50-L78 introduced Jan. 5, 2016 in https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/commit/6c5f0c537950829f4f46785457799f9047335d63#diff-bcc7b0fde7e279af33db2eaa4219e7e5.  `bootstrapLib` adds the Bootstrap JavaScript/CSS dependencies.  We could do this manually, but leveraging the work of RStudio makes this much easier.

Comment: Perhaps, I have some similar problems. Perhaps you know, what's going on? See [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56989205/5784831), 
[Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56986638/5784831) and
[Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56983105/5784831). I am working on the Rmarkdown level (preferred).